# looking for a inequality of $(a-b)^2>...$

Tags: real-analysis

i know the inequality

$
(a+b)^2\leq 2a^2+2b^2
$

but is there also some similar inequality for a minus sign?

i need to bound:

$
(a-b)^2\geq \dots
$

i am looking for a bound like

$
(a-b)^2\geq c|a^2-b^2| 
$ for some c>0

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: What about $(a-b)^2 \ge 0$? – Seriously: What terms would you expect as a lower bound?

Comment: i added something, thank you for your comment

Comment: Such an estimate cannot hold: Set $a=1+\epsilon$ and $b=1$, then consider $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. $(a-b)^2\geq |ca-db|$ for some $c,d>0$ would also be okay

Comment: Then choose $a=b$ to see that necessarily $c=d$, so that does not help.

Answer (score 1):

No way.

Without loss of generality we can assume $a>b$.

The inequality $$(a-b)^2-c \left(a^2-b^2\right)<0$$
has infinite solutions for any $b,c$ we can take
$$a>\frac{-b(c+1)}{c-1};\;\text{ if }c>1,b\le 0\\b < a< \frac{b(c+1)}{1-c};\;\text{ if }0<c<1,b>0$$
Therefore there is no bound like the one you are looking for.